# Getting Error On First Run With Buildbot

Tags: python, django, buildbot

I'm following the docs trying to get Buildbot working for the first time and I keep getting the same error:

```
2017-08-04 13:58:45-0400 [-] while starting BuildMaster
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/mike/tmp/bb-master/sandbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1442, in gotResult
        _inlineCallbacks(r, g, deferred)
      File "/home/mike/tmp/bb-master/sandbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1386, in _inlineCallbacks
        result = g.send(result)
      File "/home/mike/tmp/bb-master/sandbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildbot/util/service.py", line 53, in reconfigServiceWithBuildbotConfig
        yield svc.reconfigServiceWithBuildbotConfig(new_config)
      File "/home/mike/tmp/bb-master/sandbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1532, in unwindGenerator
        return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "/home/mike/tmp/bb-master/sandbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1386, in _inlineCallbacks
        result = g.send(result)
      File "/home/mike/tmp/bb-master/sandbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildbot/www/service.py", line 209, in reconfigServiceWithBuildbotConfig
        self.setupSite(new_config)
      File "/home/mike/tmp/bb-master/sandbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/buildbot/www/service.py", line 274, in setupSite
        "could not find plugin %s; is it installed?" % (key,))
    exceptions.RuntimeError: could not find plugin grid_view; is it installed?
```

You can see in the last error message it says the `grid_view` plugin could not be found. I'm not sure if I need to do anything else not outlined in the docs. I'm assuming when installing Buildbot it would install the proper plugins needed.

Has anyone came across this error when running Buildbot? Any ideas on how to get Buildbot running?

```
Python version: 2.7.5
Buildbot version: 0.9.10
Twisted version: 17.5.0
```

[Link](http://docs.buildbot.net/current/tutorial/firstrun.html) to the docs I'm following.

Comment: Could be a problem in the documentation (or a missed step), but your immediate problem is probably solved with: `pip install buildbot-grid-view`

Comment: That got me up and running! I tried following the directions multiple times starting from scratch each time to make sure I didn't miss a step. I may have to open a ticket with Buildbot. Make an answer so I can give you credit :)

Comment: Great to hear - I'll post an answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like an issue with BuildBot's documentation (or something changed in the process and the documentation hasn't been updated).

If you run the following command, your install should work.

```
pip install buildbot-grid-view
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the solution was to install buildbot like this:

```
pip install 'buildbot[bundle]'
```

Information found in [Buildbot docs First run](https://docs.buildbot.net/2.6.0/tutorial/firstrun.html).